# (520) function "_main2" is never called

Tags: c, mplab

I am new to this site and only a week into learning c code using  Mplab 5.45. I did manage to make a working program on and newer pic 16f152575 with Mplab 6.00 ,but that one was MMC compatible. Now I am trying an older pic16f914 which does not have the "easy" MCC functions and I am having issues with manually configuring the IO pins.

THE XC8 COMPILER BUILDS MY PROGRAM, BUT, it says what is in the title of this question."(520) function "_main2" is never called", So , I am missing something simple somewhere !
FYI: I did spell configure wrong in the file name on purpose!
Any Ideas or help would be appreciated!
Thanks Fran

```
    /* 
 * File:   conifigure.c
 * Author: fran
 * Created on April 23, 2022, 11:53 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include "plowheader.h"
#include "pic16f914.h"


int main2(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    while(1)
    TRISA = 0x14;       
    TRISB = 0xEC;       
    TRISC = 0x7D;       
    TRISD = 0x7F;       
    TRISE = 0x0F;
    
    PORTAbits.RA0 = 0;  
    PORTAbits.RA1 = 0;  
    PORTAbits.RA2 = 1;  
    PORTAbits.RA3 = 0;  
    PORTAbits.RA4 = 1;  
    PORTAbits.RA5 = 0;  
    PORTAbits.RA6 = 0;  
    PORTAbits.RA7 = 0;  
        
    PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;   
    PORTBbits.RB1 = 0;   
    PORTBbits.RB2 = 1;      
    PORTBbits.RB3 = 1;  
    PORTBbits.RB4 = 0;   
    PORTBbits.RB5 = 1;      
    PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;       
    PORTBbits.RB7 = 1;  
           
    PORTCbits.RC0 = 1;   
    PORTCbits.RC1 = 0;      
    PORTCbits.RC2 = 1;      
    PORTCbits.RC3 = 1; 
    PORTCbits.RC4 = 1;      
    PORTCbits.RC5 = 1;      
    PORTCbits.RC6 = 1;      
    PORTCbits.RC7 = 0; 
            
    PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;  
    PORTDbits.RD1 = 1;     
    PORTDbits.RD2 = 1;      
    PORTDbits.RD3 = 1;     
    PORTDbits.RD4 = 1;      
    PORTDbits.RD5 = 1;      
    PORTDbits.RD6 = 1;    
    PORTDbits.RD7 = 0;   
                
    PORTEbits.RE0 = 1;     
    PORTEbits.RE1 = 1;     
    PORTEbits.RE2 = 1; 

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about the message?  Do you ever call main2?  The entry point of a C program is named `main`

Comment: I do not remember calling out main 2 . Where and how do I do that ? In this configure file or another attached file ? My main program c file is called  "main" with no #2. Thanks for replying !

Comment: Line 14 of this file.

Comment: line 14 of what file?

Comment: How many files did you post?

Comment: one. line 14 is int main2(int argc, char** argv), but that is what is not being called.

Comment: which is exactly what the message is telling you.

Comment: here is a section of the main and I have conifigure included.    ``` * Author: ChieF_plow_controllers
 * EMAIL : plow_controllers@twc.com
 * Created on April 23, 2022, 8:27 AM
 */
#include <xc.h>
#include "conifigure.c"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main(void) 
{/*A*/   //SETS HIGH LOW ``` and here is what warning I get ``` ./conifigure.c:15:: warning: (520) function "_main2" is never called ``` when I build the file.

Comment: how do I add another section of code in this post ? what I just did does not show up correctly.